# Error when calling Drive.Files.get(fileId,{alt: 'media'}) in Google apps script (Google Drive API / REST V2)

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, google-drive-api

I got an error when I try to get the content of a file (mimetype is "text/csv") stored in my Google drive using Drive.Files.get(fileId,{alt: 'media'}) from a Google apps script (I'm using Google Drive API / REST V2).

The strange thing is that the content of my file seems to be returned inside the message of the error, as follow:

```
{
   "message":"Response Code: 200. Message: id\turl\tthumbnail_url\ttitle\tpublishedAt\tdescription\tchanelId\tcategoryId\ttags\tduration\tdislikeCount\tviewCount\tlikeCount\tcommentCount\r\n....",
   "name":"HttpResponseException",
   "fileName":"Code",
   "lineNumber":142,
   "stack":"\tat Code:142 (updateChannelVideos)\n",
   "statusCode":200
}
```

Do you know how I can get the content of my file, from the server side, without using service like UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to fetch the file from Drive.

Comment: It is as simple as: var myFile = Drive.Files.get(fileID,{alt: 'media'});
I'm using the Drive advanced service provided by GAS (see: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive))

Comment: I'm providing a little more background to this: at first I was trying to append new lines to the .CSV hosted on my drive. It seems that cannot be done without getting the content of .CSV first, so here I am. If you know a way to do this using the advanced drive service of GAS I'll be glad to learn!

Comment: try going though the sheets api if you want to edit the file.  I dont think that app scripts is going to let you download a file.  all your going to get with files.get is the file metadata not its contents

Comment: From your question and comments, I found that you cannot use UrlFetchApp and ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%22`` of a scope. It seems that in your situation, there are other scopes that you can use and cannot use. And also if there are such limitations for the methods and APIs, can I ask you about them? I think that providing such materials will help users think of your solutions or workarounds. Can you provide such information?

Comment: I've created an issue tracker at the following link.  [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685)  Please click the star to show support for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed this issue using:

```
var fetchstring='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+FILE_ID
fetchstring=fetchstring+'?mimeType=text/csv&alt=media';
var file_to_upload = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchstring, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }}).getBlob();
```

Adapat the mimetype / getBlob parts to your use case

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Google Apps Script can't handle a response from `var myFile = Drive.Files.get(fileID,{alt: 'media'});` and if not already you might want to file as a bug.

**Edit:** [updated related issue ticket here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685).

Instead of using the `Drive` Advanced Service you might find it easier to use `DriveApp`. Depending on the rest of your code no additional scopes would be required when mixing `Drive` and `DriveApp` calls.

For example you could use:

```
var myFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();
```

Comment: Sadly, it does not work unless I explicitely add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" in my manifest file. And I don't want to do that.

Comment: `DriveApp` generally does not work without full drive scope, while `Drive` can, since you explicitly determine what you want to request in each call.

Comment: I've created an issue tracker at the following link.  [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149104685)  Please click the star to show support for the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Wells - Updated the issue ticket in the post